# XML file not updating through php script on hosting server

Tags: php, xml

Content not updating in xml file on hosting server.

```
<?php
 $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $xml->formatOutput = true;
 $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $xml->load('rates.xml');

 //Get item Element
 $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('rates')->item(0);

 //Load child elements
 $name = $element->getElementsByTagName('gold')->item(0);
 $comment = $element->getElementsByTagName('silver')->item(0);

 //Replace old elements with new
 $element->replaceChild($name, $name);
 $element->replaceChild($comment, $comment);
 ?>
<body><hr>
 <form method="POST" action='' autocomplete="off">
     Enter Gold Rate (Rs/10g) : <input required type="text" value="<?php echo $name->nodeValue  ?>" name="gold-rate" pattern="^[0-9]{5}$" placeholder="for 10g"></br></br>
Enter Silver Rate (Rs/kg) :  <input required type="text" value="<?php echo $comment->nodeValue  ?>"  name="silver-rate" pattern="^[0-9]{5}$" placeholder="for 10g"/></br></br>
 <input name="submit" type="submit" />

 </form><hr>
</body>
 <?php


 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 { 
$name->nodeValue = $_POST['gold-rate'];
$comment->nodeValue = $_POST['silver-rate'];
htmlentities($xml->save('sample.xml'));

 }


 ?>
```

Above code is about form submission of two values i am trying to save in XML and then display it elsewhere. On local-host it got success, but on server this php script is unable to change the data of my XML file. Permissions for the folder i set is 755 and all files at 644. Tried changing the permissions and ended up with 500 internal error. As this looks server-side security matter, i have no clue where to end up looking for solution.
Server is running on PHP 5.6, tried solutions from other users but nothing fruitful. Should i have to change something in php or do i have to contact my hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP server normally runs with an user without permission to modify files on the server. Most web applications store any data which can be modified in a database.

If you want to have a file or directory writable by the web server, you can try:

- make the parent directory writable to the web server.
- run a small php script which creates the file or directory
- restore the original permission on the directory

And after that you can write to the file from your original php file.

I guess you get a 500 error if either your php script or its parent directory is world writable. Depending on your hosting provider, it may work if you create a separate directory for any files written to by the server.

Comment: actually the xml in which i saved the data is different than i loaded and its there in the code 'sample.xml' , the script works super fine, thanks for above info